# Linq запрос на выбор элемента массива по достижению опереденной суммы значений предыдущих элементов

Tags: c#, linq

Есть массив с предстоящими платежами(например):

```
List<Payment> payments = new List<Payment>();
payments.Add(new Payment() { Date = "2020-01-01", Sum = 100 });
payments.Add(new Payment() { Date = "2020-02-01", Sum = 200 });
payments.Add(new Payment() { Date = "2020-03-01", Sum = 300 });
payments.Add(new Payment() { Date = "2020-04-01", Sum = 400 });
payments.Add(new Payment() { Date = "2020-05-01", Sum = 500 });
```

И есть сумма уже внесенных в кассу денег.

```
double TotalPayments = 600.00;
```

Как получить на выходе объект с данными следующего платежа?

```
var NextPayment = ?
Console.WriteLine(NextPayment.Date); // 2020-04-01
Console.WriteLine(NextPayment.Sum); // 400
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом посредством linq можно реализовать подобный выбор?

Спасибо!

Comment: ищешь первый payment сумма с которым больше чем текущая - он и будет следующим платежом

Comment: Дико неэффективно, но вот `var ret = payments.Where((p, i) => payments.Where((p1, i1)=>i1<i).Sum(z=>z.Sum) >= 600).First();`

Comment: tym32167, благодарю! Именно то, что требовалось! ;)

Comment: `double sum = 0; var NextPayment = payments.SkipWhile(p => (sum += p.Sum) <= TotalPayments).First();` - более эффективно, но с побочным эффектом. В общем, лучше без linq'а сделать.

Comment: Не храните деньги в `double`. Используйте `decimal`.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Нужно использовать накопитель и пропускать элементы пока он не примет определенное значение, а после того как примет – взять только следующий элемент.

```
int TotalPayments = 600;
int counter = 0;

var nextPayment = payments
    .SkipWhile(x =>
    {
        counter += x.Sum;
        return counter <= TotalPayments;
    })
    .Take(1)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine(nextPayment.Date); // 2020-04-01
Console.WriteLine(nextPayment.Sum); // 400
```